# ¿Evitar espacio en blanco en el texto al pasar a una nueva linea en el HTML?

Tags: html, css

**Si al escribir un texto en HTML pasamos a una nueva línea, en la presentación se añade un espacio en blanco**, por ejemplo si en el editor escribo:

```
<p>Lorem
ipsum</p>
```

Aparecerá en la ventana del navegador (en mi caso Chromiun 79.0.3945.79 y Firefox 72.0.1):

```
Lorem ipsum
```

Aunque este comportamiento pueda ser el deseado en la mayoría de los casos, no lo es siempre. **¿Cómo puedo evitar esto?**

> **Editado**
>
> Salida esperada:

```
Loremipsum
```

***Nota:*** he estado probando con la [propiedad CSS "white-space"](https://www.lawebera.es/xhtml-css/css-avanzado-propiedad-%E2%80%9Cwhite-space%E2%80%9D.php)

Comment: he dejado una solución con CSS usando 'word-spacing', creo que es lo que necesitabas, échale un vistazo por si te sirve. Un saludo

Answer (score 4):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Después de entender mejor lo que se pedía, para conseguirlo es necesario aplicar JavaScript, hasta donde yo se no es posible conseguirlo solo con CSS.

Un ejemplo sencllo con jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/yqdh1sfu/

```
<p id="parrafo">Lorem
ipsum
</p>
```

El código JS:

```
function procesarTexto(idElement) {
    let text = $('#' + idElement).text();
    let finalText = text.replace('\n', '');
    $('#' + idElement).text(finalText);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    procesarTexto('parrafo');
});
```

---

RESPUESTA ORIGINAL (Enfocada a preservar los saltos de línea el texto):

Puedes usar el tag `<pre>` para que te respete los saltos de línea:

```html
<pre>Lorem
ipsum</pre>
```

Otra opción es aplicar css con `white-space`:

```html
<p style="white-space: pre;">Lorem
ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no respondes a mi pregunta. No trato de conservar saltos de línea, trato de evitar el espacio en blanco que generan. El tag `pre` preserva los espacios en blanco, no preserva los saltos en sí, se preservan porque se consideran espacios en blanco. `pre` se puede usar por ejemplo para compartir un fragmento de código manteniendo el *indentado* y si, *saltos de línea* dentro de un párrafo si se requiere, aunque para esto hay otras etiquetas HTML específicas.

Comment: Lo siento pero no entiendo entonces qué pretendes, ¿ Cual sería la salida esperada en tu ejemplo ? O dicho de otra forma existe un caracter '\n' en el texto del html, "Lorem\nIpsun",  que por defecto se convierte en un espacio, ' ', o bien con `pre` se represetna como un salto de línea, si no quieres preservarlo, ¿ cómo quieres representarlo ?

Comment: Espero `Loremipsum`. Se que es un ejemplo tonto, pero cuando me es posible adapto el problema para simplificar la cuestión. En cuanto a `pre`, especifico: se usa para indicar que el contenido se trate como texto plano, es decir no sea interpretado, así mantiene los espacios.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, pero me temo que es necesario usar JavaScript para conseguir lo que pides, sólo con CSS no es viable.

Comment: he dejado una solución con CSS usando 'word-spacing', creo que es lo que necesitabas, échale un vistazo por si te sirve. Un saludo

Comment: En mi opinión `word-spacing` no resuelve el problema, ya que une todas las palabras, no solo las separadas por un salto de línea.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas, por los comentarios que leo arriba, es eliminar el espacio entre las palabras, y esto lo puedes hacer con CSS utilizando 'word-spacing'. En este caso la clase CSS tendría que ser algo así:

```css
 .sinespacios {word-spacing: -0.5em}
```

```html
      <pre class="sinespacios">Lorem ipsum</pre>
```

Tendrás que probar para ajustar cuanto debes pegar las palabras. De todas formas te comparto aquí un par de enlaces sobre el uso de esta propiedad por si te pueden ser de ayuda.

https://cssreference.io/property/word-spacing/

https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/referencia-css2/word-spacing